# YUI CSS template class .yui-t7 gap at top of page

Tags: css, yui

Hoping someone who is familiar with YUI's CSS templates can help me debug a CSS problem. I'm using a free html resume template I found on the net, and I want to print it on paper via the browser's print function. I am not publishing this on the web. My problem is that there's about a 75-pixel gap between the top of the first div and the browser's display area that I can't figure out how to get rid of. Looking at the image below, there is a red arrow that points it out.

[YUI CSS gap between top of screen and div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prG30.png)

The template can be found [hosted at this location](http://sampleresumetemplate.net/srt-resume.html).

What I've done:

- Open the element inspector in the browser. Looks like the gap is between the `<body>` and first `<div>`.
- Downloaded the YUI CSS file to look at. Checked out all the `div` selectors, nothing interesting.
- Looked at the `.yui-t7` class, nothing interesting there either.
- My suspicion is that some of the `float` and `clear` are adding up and causing the space, but this is outside my expertise.

I was looking for height values or padding that would clue me in on how to change it, but honestly I don't see heights anywhere in either css file. I admit that I am not strong in CSS at all. I'm open to other solutions too, just enough to get the thing printed so I can send it out!

Comment: Is there a hosted version of the template somewhere (so we don't have to download >> unzip >> open up)?

Comment: I just edited the link in the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This BR Adds a little space**
[image: This BR Adds a little space]

**The margin on this div adds the rest of the space**
[image: The margin on this div adds the rest of the space]

Comment: That margin was the main culprit. The copy I downloaded in the zip didn't have the `<br>` - odd. I just looked up the `margin` and indeed when there are two values the first is applied to top and bottom. Thank you very much; glad to have fast help late at night :)

Comment: Glad I could help :)